# XMLStarlet: Editing a node with specific attribute value

Tags: bash, shell, xpath, xmlstarlet

I want to edit the value of the node "title" in the following XML file, using XMLStarlet. Only the title node which is a child node of locale with attribute name="de-DE" should be edited.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <package xmlns="http://apple.com/itunes/importer" version="software5.4">
      <software>
        <software_metadata app_platform="ios">
          <versions>
            <version string="1.1.1">
              <locales>
                <locale name="de-DE">
                  <title>title_DE</title>
                </locale>
                <locale name="en-US">
                  <title>title_EN</title>
                </locale>
              </locales>
            </version>
          </versions>
        </software_metadata>
      </software>
    </package>
```

I tried the following command, but it does nothing:

```
xml ed -N x="http://apple.com/itunes/importer" -u '/x:package/x:software/x:software_metadata/x:versions/x:version/x:locales/x:locale[@name='de-DE']/x:title' -v 'new titel' metadata.xml
```

Using the same XPath query for selecting works fine:

```
xml sel -N x="http://apple.com/itunes/importer" -t -v "/x:package/x:software/x:software_metadata/x:versions/x:version/x:locales/x:locale[@name='de-DE']/x:title" metadata.xml
```

Does anybody know why selecting is working but editing is not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your edit statement you should also use double quotes on the outer definition. The way it is now **@name='de-DE'** is the problem because the single quote ends the command.

```
xml ed -N x="http://apple.com/itunes/importer" -u '/x:package/x:software/x:software_metadata/x:versions/x:version/x:locales/x:locale[@name="de-DE"]/x:title' -v 'new titel' metadata.xml
```

My general preference is to use single quotes first and on the inside use double quotes but since both works it is up to choice as long as consistency is kept.